# Is it safe to backup my HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, grub, bsod

Currently I see 2 parameters reaching design limits, namely Reallocated Sector Count as well as Spin Retry Count from the SMART data. The computer boots once out of 10 attempts and I have seen BSODs and GRUB rescue messages too.

My problem is that I see both way over the threshold! What can I do about this? Is it safe to back up my HDD or will that further aggravate the problem by increasing the number of read operations?

SMART screenshot:
[image]

[link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrltX.png)

Comment: It does not matter if its "safe" to backup your HDD.  You need to backup your HDD if you can only boot 10% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

The threshold works the other way around: It’s gone bad when Current < Threshold. That’s why it’s only a warning in your case.

Although that many spin retries clearly aren’t normal, so do backup your data. :)

Comment: Haha, SMART data seems completely nonsensical to me. So a low value is good for all the parameters?

Comment: Generally, higher “Current” values are better. Most of the time, it’s better to look at the “Data” value. Meaning: 2 reallocated sectors and 13 spin retries.

Answer (score 1):

The question whether it's safe to backup your data is the wrong one. If your disk is going bad (or you think it is), backing up your data should be your first concern. Don't try repairs yet, **back up first**. Instead of repeating myself, I point to [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/719860/hard-drive-failure-cannot-run-chkdsk-recovery/719866#719866).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How imminent is my HDD's failure in your opinion?