# recover corrupted txt file

Tags: windows, data-recovery, file-corruption, repair

I had a `txt` file saved in my hard drive for about 2 month and today i found out that the data inside of it are gone, they are not encoded messed up or something like that, all the data are just turned to spaces, the files is not empty it just includes bunch of spaces, and this also happened to an other text file in the same drive as well,

the data is really really important for me. please is there any chance i could restore it? any help would be appreciated.

is there a software that could like restore old versions of a file?

Comment: I hope you have a good backup to revert to...

Comment: @spikey_richie i have nothing, i only saved the data in that file and put the file somewhere safe in my hard drive

Comment: This is most likely to have happened as a result of a file system corruption, so you should run a file system check as soon as possible. Depending on how the files were edited, there may be deleted earlier versions which may be recoverable. Otherwise, as @spikey_richie says, you'll need to use your back-ups. If you don't have back-ups, then the files can't have been important.

Comment: Well, if it is **somewhere safe** then why not just take it from there?

Comment: @AFH the file was important, I'm just a fucking retard

Comment: Well as others have pointed out, even if it isn't the answer you want, the short answer is no you can't recover it

Answer (score 0):

If two of your text files are damaged, it is likely that others are as well.

My suspicion is your hard disk is degrading. Stop using it

Instead of repeating my earlier SU answer, [I'll link to it here](https://superuser.com/a/719866/141909)